# Pandas does not sep columns properly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, python-3.6

basically after loading my csv file, I cant proceed because columns are not getting separated
The file comes from a xlm webpage. I just copied all and paste in on Excel and saved as a CSV file.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:/Users/Igor/Desktop/sportheca/Pasta1.csv', sep=';', encoding='ISO-8859-1')
df
```

Output:

```
    {
0   "resultado": "ok",
1   "ndet": "220",
2   "det": [
3   {
4   "codigo": "55",
... ...
383690  "categoria": "CODO",
383691  "setor": "CoDo"
383692  }
383693  ]
383694  }
```

Any tips for solving this?

Comment: can you post a sample screenshot of your csv file?

Comment: @arjunsiva Don't recommend posting screenshots. See here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1643973 Instead, a sample from the CSV file should be copied and pasted into the question.

Answer (score 0):

scrape directly from the site and use xmltodict to make a python dictionary out of the XML data structure :

```
import requests
import xmltodict

url = "https://whatever_your_site/your.xml"
response = requests.get(url)
data = xmltodict.parse(response.content)
```

after that try to read it into a pandas dataframe.